# Setting custom attrribute on svg element (Raphael)

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, attributes, raphael

When I set id to svg element

```
var circle = paper.circle(x, y, r);
circle.node.id = 'circle-id';
```

everything is fine and I can see expected result like this when browsing document with the debugger:

```
<circle cx="320" cy="240" r="4" fill="none" stroke="#000" id="circle-id" />
```

Then I'm able to get this element by id via `document.getElementById` method or via jQuery.
But adding some other attributes fails. If I try to add attribute `custom`:

```
circle.node.custom = 'custom-attr';
```

I see no effect.

What kind of attributes can we add to SVG element using Raphael and how to add arbitrary attributes?

Comment: why do you want to set a custom-attr?

Comment: @stewbydoo, I wanted some html elements to communicate with some svg elements. For example on some div mouseover change some svg element's background and on mouseout change it back. But changing back with `$('elem-elector').attr('fill', '')` failed. With storing `original-color` attribute on svg element this feature can be implemented easily.

Comment: Sounds to me like you'd be far better off using the :hover pseudo class rather than rolling your own implementation. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/hover.html

Comment: @Robert Longson what I need is to link some div hover to some changes in SVG element. I have some divs paired with SVG paths so I don't think I can use CSS `:hover` declaration.

Comment: I mean hovering on div does not affect on div but on the linked SVG element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`node` is a DOM element, `id` is a standard property on elements to quickly read/write its value. Use the `setAttribute` method to set non-standard attributes.

```
circle.node.setAttribute('custom', 'custom-attr');
```

Comment: Constantly coding with jQuery did not let me to think about how DOM actually organized. Thank you!

Comment: Lesson: learn more about actual Javascript. jQuery is not the holy grail.